# rename files with specific scheme for srt files

Tags: regex, bash, perl, rename

I'm trying to rename a bunch of media files but I can't get to build the correct regular expression. My purpose is to rename the files keeping only the extension, with suffix if there is such as `en.srt`, `fr.srt`, `du.srt` or `ne.srt`.

I tried several commands and got very close to my purpose but not yet :

```
rename -n "s/(.*)\/.*\.([[:alnum:]]+|[[:alpha:]]+\.srt)$/\$1\/\$1\.\$2/" */*
```

$2 fails to capture the language suffix of the .srt extensions. It just gives the `.srt`.

Here is how I built my regex :

```
dir/file
dir := .*
file :=  filename.ext
filename := .*
ext := .[a-z0-9]+ or [a-z]+.srt <EOL>
```

**It seems that the problem is that .srt matches normal extension and regex doesn't care it also matches the second or clause.**

```
rename -n "s/(.*)\/.*\.([a-z0-9]{3}|[a-z]{2}\.srt)$/\$1\/\$1\.\$2/" */*
```

**How can I correctly catch the extension to input it in the output ?**

```
pi@raspbian-AH:/media/adrien_EMD/Movies $ rename -n "s/(.*)\/.*\.([a-z]{2}\.srt|[a-z0-9]{3})$/\$1\/\$1\.\$2/" */*
rename(Inside Out (2015)/Inside.Out.2015.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.mp4, Inside Out (2015)/Inside Out (2015).mp4)
rename(Seven Samurai (1954)/Seven Samurai (1954).en.srt, Seven Samurai (1954)/Seven Samurai (1954).srt)
rename(Seven Samurai (1954)/Seven Samurai (1954).fr.srt, Seven Samurai (1954)/Seven Samurai (1954).srt)
rename(The Wizard of Oz (1939)/The.Wizard.of.Oz.1939.1080p.BrRip.x264.BOKUTOX.YIFY.mp4, The Wizard of Oz (1939)/The Wizard of Oz (1939).mp4)
```

Seven Samurai shouldn't appear as it is already correctly named.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some representative example names and what each of those names should be mapped to.

Comment: try this 
`/([^\w]+srt)/g` this will search files end with .srt

Comment: @gihan, can you please explain what does it do?

Comment: this simply does capture the word end with `.srt` and other things i meant renaming this you have to do programmatically.in java you can use `Pattern  and Matcher ` classes

Answer (score 1):

I separated cases using a find command. I just need to put the appropriate rename command now.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Media files : "
find . -type f ! -regex ".*\/\..*" ! -regex ".*\.srt$"

echo "Subtitles files : "
find . -type f ! -regex ".*\/\..*" -regex ".*\.srt$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does raspbian not have grep? This should filter out srt files.

```
for i in `ls | grep -v '.srt'`;  do echo $i; done
```

Then you can add your rename logic, Example:

```
for i in `ls | grep -v '.srt'`;  do echo $i; rename -n "s/(.*)\/.*\.([a-z0-9]{3}|[a-z]{2}\.srt)$/\$1\/\$1\.\$2/" $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This question should be tagged with 'perl' because the 'rename' being used here is the Perl version, not the 'util-linux' version, and the problem is due to the way that Perl regular expressions work.  More specifically, it's due to the interaction between greedy matching with `*` and backtracking.  The easiest way to fix it is to make the second `.*` non-greedy by appending a `?`:

```
rename -n "s/(.*)\/.*?\.([a-z]{2}\.srt|[a-z0-9]{3})$/\$1\/\$1\.\$2/" */*
```

Replacing `[a-z]` with `[[:alpha:]]` and `[a-z0-9]` with `[[:alnum:]]`, as in the first example code in the question is a good idea, but note that they will also match upper case letters.

Comment: Advice seems good but I don't have much time on my hand, I will try to understand and to use that later. Flag changed thanks to your advice